# Abrindo 2 modais com mesma classe - CSS

Tags: php, html, css, webforms, modal

Galera, mt boa noite. Tudo bem?

Minha dúvida é relativamente simples. Tenho um modal box de apresentação de um simples texto. Gostaria de utilizá-lo também para mostrar, assim que o usuário clicar num outro link, um campo de texto, em que poderá recuperar a senha esquecida do cadastro. Tal senha será enviada por e-mail.

A configuração do PHP eu consigo fazer tranquila, só fico na dúvida mesmo em utilizar corretamente o CSS.

Segue código:

```css
<style>
/* CSS para modal box para visualização das regras */
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#999);
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}


/* CSS para envio da senha ("esqueceu sua senha?") */


</style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   </head>
<body>
  <table><tr><th>
     <a href="#openModal">regras</a>
          
      <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
         <a href="#close" title="Fechar" class="close">X</a>
              <h2>Regras de Reserva</h2>
     <p>Texto Simples</p> 
              </div>
          </div> </th></tr></table>
  
  Minha ideira era colocar mais um painel desse, porém com um <input type="text"> e um botão <input type="submit">. 
                                                        
  
</body>
</html>
```

```css
<style>
/* CSS para modal box para visualização das regras */
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#999);
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}


/* CSS para envio da senha ("esqueceu sua senha?") */


</style>
```

Só não sei o motivo do código não ter rodado corretamente aí no painel.

Grande abs!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo! Pelo que entendi vc precisa fazer outra modal com o input e o botão de enviar, certo? Bem se for isso basta apenas usar o mesmo método, colocando o input e o botão dentro da modal.Segue o código:

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
#openModal.show{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#999);
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="#openModal">regras</a>

                <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#close" title="Fechar" id="closex" class="close">X</a>
                        <h2>Regras de Reserva</h2>
                        <p>Texto Simples</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="#openModal2">modal2</a>

                <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#close" title="Fechar" id="closex" class="close">X</a>
                        <h2>Regras de Reserva</h2>
                        <p>Texto Simples</p>
                        <input type="text"> e um botão
                        <input type="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aguardo pra saber se resolveu, abs!